# Connect from C# to a digital scale

Tags: c#, usb

I'm trying to figure out a method of connecting from C# code to a digital scale. The particular scale is an Ohaus SP202 digital scale which comes with a USB connection.  I would like to read the weight measured on the scale programmatically. I don't have the scale yet, I'm just doing the research before hand.

Has anyone done this before? I've been doing research on the internet and didn't find anything worth mentioning yet.

Answer (score 6):

USB Hardware communication popularly works one of three ways.

1. Proprietary software talks to hardware via proprietary driver.
2. Devices have a Serial emulation chip (e.g. [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/FTProducts.htm#FT232R)) When you plug in the scale you just need to install the Virtual Comm Port drivers and the device shows up as a comm port on your system.  Then it is as easy as using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort to talk to the device.
3. The device implements a HID profile and will be available through your OS's HID system.  I've used [this .NET HID](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm) library on Windows to successfully talk with barcode scanners that implement HID.  The HID library will send data to you from the hardware in chunks that you decipher based on the hardware you are talking to.

With method 2 and 3 you will just need to find the data format for the scale that you are talking to.  The scales that I have used send updates every second or so with the weight and other information shown on the hardware UI, such as if the load has stabilized or not.

Looking at their discussion forums it looks like their scales use method 2 (http://ohaus.com/support/forum_messages.asp?topicid=584) and that you need to Poll the scale by sending a "P\r\n" it will then respond with the characters that are shown on the display (http://ohaus.com/support/forum_messages.asp?topicid=802).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that specific scale, but I have connected to other digital scales previously. Basically it is usually just doing serial communications via the USB to Com converter.

If the scale has an API for this all the better, but if not then you will just be using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort which is pretty standard serial programming. [A starter article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/serialcommunication.aspx?fid=119621&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=176&select=1065635)

Comment: Second that. I have also done it against an industrial scale and all it takes is some serial communications and reading the manual to the scale to get the messages correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any details on this scale, but I've done some USB stuff.

Its most likely using usb interrupt to transfer the data.  All usb mice also use interrupt, so if you can figure out how to read the mouse signal (with using an HID api), then it should be exactly the same as the scale, except the data format returned would be completely different.

run on ftw

Comment: Very often the USB-device of this sort adds an emulated com-port so Its just as easy as if it was an scale connected to the ra232-port.

Comment: actually it's more likely that data send over bulk pipe. excluding hid the interrupt pipe used for notification and not for data transfers. 
Data acquisition devices use bulk pipes if properly designed.

Answer (score 0):

Scales was one of the first devices I ever had to read data from. At that time, it was just a serial port and I'm guessing that you'd still be able to read from the serial port with [SerialPort.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net).

Here's the code for Serial Port transfer on Windows

[Reference](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/90aa91e584ec2f7e25002c157ad6bd42e87aa618/src/SerialPort.Net/Windows/WindowsSerialPortDevice.cs#L1)

```
using Device.Net;
using Device.Net.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SerialPort.Net.Windows
{
    public class WindowsSerialPortDevice : DeviceBase, IDevice
    {
        #region Fields
        private readonly int _BaudRate;
        private readonly byte _ByteSize;
        private bool disposed;
        private readonly Parity _Parity;
        private SafeFileHandle _ReadSafeFileHandle;
        private readonly StopBits _StopBits;
        private ushort ReadBufferSize { get; }
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        public bool IsInitialized => _ReadSafeFileHandle != null && !_ReadSafeFileHandle.IsInvalid;
        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: No need to implement this. The property probably shouldn't exist at the base level
        /// </summary>
        public IApiService ApiService { get; }
        public ConnectedDeviceDefinition ConnectedDeviceDefinition { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public WindowsSerialPortDevice(
            string deviceId,
            int baudRate = 9600,
            StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One,
            Parity parity = Parity.None,
            byte byteSize = 8,
            ushort readBufferSize = 1024,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = null,
            IApiService apiService = null) : base(
                deviceId,
                loggerFactory,
                (loggerFactory ?? NullLoggerFactory.Instance).CreateLogger<WindowsSerialPortDevice>())
        {
            ApiService = apiService ?? new ApiService(null);

            ConnectedDeviceDefinition = new ConnectedDeviceDefinition(DeviceId, DeviceType.SerialPort);

            if ((byteSize == 5 && stopBits == StopBits.Two) || (stopBits == StopBits.OnePointFive && byteSize > 5))
                throw new ArgumentException(Messages.ErrorInvalidByteSizeAndStopBitsCombo);

            if (byteSize is < 5 or > 8)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(byteSize), Messages.ErrorByteSizeMustBeFiveToEight);

            if (baudRate is < 110 or > 256000)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(baudRate), Messages.ErrorBaudRateInvalid);

            if (stopBits == StopBits.None)
                throw new ArgumentException(Messages.ErrorMessageStopBitsMustBeSpecified, nameof(stopBits));

            ReadBufferSize = readBufferSize;
            _BaudRate = baudRate;
            _ByteSize = byteSize;
            _StopBits = stopBits;
            _Parity = parity;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => Task.Run(Initialize, cancellationToken);

        private uint Write(byte[] data) => data == null ? 0 : ApiService.AWriteFile(_ReadSafeFileHandle, data, data.Length, out var bytesWritten, 0) ? (uint)bytesWritten : 0;

        public override Task<uint> WriteAsync(byte[] data, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            ValidateConnection();
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var bytesWritten = Write(data);
                Logger.LogDataTransfer(new Trace(false, data));
                return bytesWritten;
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task<TransferResult> ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            ValidateConnection();

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var buffer = new byte[ReadBufferSize];
                var bytesRead = Read(buffer);
                var transferResult = new TransferResult(buffer, bytesRead);
                Logger.LogDataTransfer(new Trace(false, transferResult));
                return transferResult;
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task Flush(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            ValidateConnection();

            return Task.Run(() => ApiService.APurgeComm(_ReadSafeFileHandle, APICalls.PURGE_RXCLEAR | APICalls.PURGE_TXCLEAR),
                cancellationToken);
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed)
            {
                Logger.LogWarning(Messages.WarningMessageAlreadyDisposed, DeviceId);
                return;
            }

            disposed = true;

            Logger.LogInformation(Messages.InformationMessageDisposingDevice, DeviceId);

            if (_ReadSafeFileHandle != null)
            {
                _ReadSafeFileHandle.Dispose();
                _ReadSafeFileHandle = new SafeFileHandle((IntPtr)0, true);
            }

            base.Dispose();
        }

        public void Close() => Dispose();
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void Initialize()
        {
            _ReadSafeFileHandle = ApiService.CreateReadConnection(DeviceId, FileAccessRights.GenericRead | FileAccessRights.GenericWrite);

            if (_ReadSafeFileHandle.IsInvalid) return;

            var dcb = new Dcb();

            var isSuccess = ApiService.AGetCommState(_ReadSafeFileHandle, ref dcb);

            _ = WindowsHelpers.HandleError(isSuccess, Messages.ErrorCouldNotGetCommState, Logger);

            dcb.ByteSize = _ByteSize;
            dcb.fDtrControl = 1;
            dcb.BaudRate = (uint)_BaudRate;
            dcb.fBinary = 1;
            dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = 0;
            dcb.fAbortOnError = 0;

            dcb.fParity = 1;
#pragma warning disable IDE0010 // Add missing cases
            dcb.Parity = _Parity switch
            {
                Parity.Even => 2,
                Parity.Mark => 3,
                Parity.Odd => 1,
                Parity.Space => 4,
                Parity.None => 0,
                _ => 0
            };

            dcb.StopBits = _StopBits switch
            {
                StopBits.One => 0,
                StopBits.OnePointFive => 1,
                StopBits.Two => 2,
                StopBits.None => throw new ArgumentException(Messages.ErrorMessageStopBitsMustBeSpecified),
                _ => throw new ArgumentException(Messages.ErrorMessageStopBitsMustBeSpecified),
            };
#pragma warning restore IDE0010 // Add missing cases

            isSuccess = ApiService.ASetCommState(_ReadSafeFileHandle, ref dcb);
            _ = WindowsHelpers.HandleError(isSuccess, Messages.ErrorCouldNotSetCommState, Logger);

            var timeouts = new CommTimeouts
            {
                WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0,
                ReadIntervalTimeout = 1,
                WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0,
                ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0,
                ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0
            };

            isSuccess = ApiService.ASetCommTimeouts(_ReadSafeFileHandle, ref timeouts);
            _ = WindowsHelpers.HandleError(isSuccess, Messages.ErrorCouldNotSetCommTimeout, Logger);

            Logger.LogInformation("Serial Port device initialized successfully. Port: {port}", DeviceId);
        }

        private uint Read(byte[] data)
        =>
             ApiService.AReadFile(_ReadSafeFileHandle, data, data.Length, out var bytesRead, 0)
                ? bytesRead
                : throw new IOException(Messages.ErrorMessageRead);


        private void ValidateConnection()
        {
            if (!IsInitialized)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Messages.ErrorMessageNotInitialized);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```